# How to solve an R problem with both exponential and poisson distribution?

Tags: r, probability, exponential, poisson

I have come across questions in R which deal with exponential and poisson distributions separately, but I am unsure about how to go about it when you need to use **both in the same question**

> The number of customers attending a shop in (0,t) has **Poisson distribution** with parameter βt. The time that each customer spends in the shop has **Exponential distribution** with parameter λ. Find the probability that while a particular customer is shopping, maximum k other customer arrive. Use (any) β=λ and k=2. Use 10,000 samples.

How would this be solved?

Answer (score 3):

Simulate how long it will take for that customer to be served (using `rexp`), then simulate how many customers arrive during that time (using `rpois`). You should be able to combine both steps in a single expression. Make 10,000 such 2-step simulations. In what percentage is the number of arrivals <= 2?

Since this seems to be homework, I don't want to say any more than that.

Nit-pick: I don't like the wording of the problem when it says "find the probability ... "
It would be more precise to say "*estimate* the probability ... ".